# Why use onAuthStateChanged inside a useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement authentication through firebase in a react project but all the tutorials that I see on online use onAuthStateChanged method inside a useEffect but I really dont understand what is the reason behind doing this instead of running it normally inside a function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => setCurrentUser(user)
    });
    return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

As per this logic wouldnt the function only run once, like if the user is not logged in the function will set currentuser to null and then when the user tries to login it will not setcurrentuser to user because here useffect will run only once on mount.

Maybe I have weak understanding of react hook concepts or maybe I am missing something here. I would really appreciate if someone could give an in depth explanation and explain in most basic terms as possible.

Thankss.

Comment: This is registering a listener to the `authStateChanged` event, which should happen only once, specifically when component is mounted. When the component is unmounted, `useEffect` runs the callback function to unsubscribe from the event to prevent memory leaks. There may be other ways to do this. What other alternative(s) you have in mind?

Comment: `wouldnt the function only run once` The effect will run once, setting up the listener. After that, the auth state may change multiple times, calling `(user) => setCurrentUser(user)` each time

Comment: That sounds like an answer @NicholasTower  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per this logic wouldnt the function only run once

The effect *as a whole* will just run once. When the effect runs, it executes this code:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => setCurrentUser(user));
```

That's a subscription to firebase auth telling it that every time the auth state changes you want the function `(user) => setCurrentUser(user)` to be called. The inner function will get called *at least* once, but if the user logs in or out the function will get called again every time. This will continue happening until the `unsubscribe` function is called.

Since you've (correctly) returned the `unsubscribe` function from the effect, your component will stop listening for auth state changes when the component unmounts, but not before. If the component never unmounts, it will never stop listening for auth state changes.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely clear things up for me.